# How can I avoid losing information between sessions of a multi-step form using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a multi-step form using php and sessions, but, when I go back and forth, I lose the previous values. Any suggestions to solve this issue.

```
<form id="propertyform" method="post" action="industrial.php">
    <select class="element select small" id="element_1" name="property">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="industrial" >Industrial</option>
        <option value="land" >Land</option>
        <option value="office" >Office</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you repopulating the form control values from the session?

Comment: basically i am at the first step form . <form id="propertyform"  method="post" action="industrial.php"> <select class="element select small" id="element_1" name="property"> 
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="industrial" >Industrial</option>
<option value="land" >Land</option>
<option value="office" >Office</option>

        </select></form> So when i select somehing from the drop down and  post to industrial.php and click back i want the drop down to be selected with the value selected earlier.

Comment: updated answer to add your select and the code necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the values in your forms from your session?

Example

```
<form id="step1">
     <input type="text" name="firstQuestion" id="firstQuestion" 
        <? if(isset($_SESSION['firstQuestion'])): ?> value="<?=$_SESSION['firstQuestion']?>" 
        <? endif; ?> >

     <select class="element select small" id="element_1" name="property"> 
          <option value="" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['property']) && $_SESSION['property'] == ""): ?> selected="selected"<? endif; ?> ></option> 
          <option value="industrial" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['property']) && $_SESSION['property'] == "industrial"): ?> selected="selected"<? endif; ?>>Industrial</option> 
          <option value="land" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['property']) && $_SESSION['property'] == "land"): ?> selected="selected"<? endif; ?>>Land</option> 
          <option value="office" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['property']) && $_SESSION['property'] == "office"): ?> selected="selected"<? endif; ?>>Office</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

Comment: What is this, HTML 4?  Who uses all caps on tags these days?

Comment: Do you have to check `isset` first?

Comment: i can populate values except for drop down.

Comment: @mellamokb depending upon your php installation php will give you a NOTICE if you try to call a variable that hasn't been set.  So it depends on your setup, I do it because it works across setups.

Comment: @AdityaShukla for drop downs you have to check if the value of the option is equal to your session value and add selected to the option.

Answer (score 3):

I develop a product for the Psychology market that does 250 question psychological based testing.  To make a test that isn't completely overwhelming, I break the form up into 25 question segments while outputting it in a loop via div tags with a sequential ID appended (ie. div1, div2, div3)   Each div is set to display:none but the first.

I then provide the user with a button that toggles the current div + 1 (ie if on div 1, it would do a `$(#div2).show()` etc.  Back buttons do the opposite.

The important part is that the form covers ALL divs.  Then its just a matter of swapping out the forward/back button at the end with a submit button.

Voila!  Yes, low-tech.  But FAST....and no chance to EVER lose values going forward or backward.

So, a rough truncated example:

```
<form>
  <div id="div1">
     First 25 Questions
     <input type="button">shows next div</input>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" style="display:none">
    Second 25 Questions
    <input type="submit">Submit Form</input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: awesome that's a very elegant and clever way.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent refresh and history navigation from triggering form processing, add something like this to the flow *after* the form-handler has done it's thing:

```
header("Location: myStep2.php");
```

This will redirect the user to myStep2.php and prevent stomping of values.

The caveat, if you do follow this method and you need to allow users to go back to previous pages, you will need to provide a navigation menu, button, link, etc. that will enable this.  Pressing "Back" will resubmit the previous page values.